# DKIM verification in exim4

Tags: exim, dkim

I'm confused about the `acl_smtp_dkim`.

In my main config I have

```
# DKIM verification on rcpt.
acl_smtp_dkim = acl_check_dkim
domainlist require_dkim_signed_mail_domains = gmail.com:paypal.com
dkim_verify_signers = $dkim_signers:+require_dkim_signed_mail_domains
```

And `acl_check_dkim` is defined as follows:

```
# check the DKIM signature for hosts that will definitely use it.
deny message   = DKIM required. $dkim_verify_status reason: '$dkim_verify_reason'
  sender_domains  = +require_dkim_signed_mail_domains
  dkim_signers  = +require_dkim_signed_mail_domains
  dkim_status   = none:invalid:fail

accept
```

(I actually have lines before the last `accept` verb, but I'm satisfied that they act correctly so I've missed them out here.)

Confusion:

1. `+require_dkim_signed_mail_domains` doesn't seem to work - doesn't seem to expand here. Why not?
2. Why is `dkim_signers` required here? If it's ommitted then it acts as if there is no DKIM header present (`dkim_status` shows `None`), even when there is.

Thanks.